# How to calculate the center of a D3 Diagonal Path?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree, data-visualization

**Question:** What's the best way to calculate the "*center*" of a diagonal D3 path?

**Visualization Example and Original Source:** http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/ed80661daf8e5fa89b85/

**Goal:** I'm trying overlay link/relationship descriptive text (called "predicates") on paths in a Horizontal D3 Tree.  I'd like to place them in the "*center*" of the path.  Sometimes the path is a diagonal curve and sometimes it's a straight horizontal line.

For every link path, I have a source node and a target node and I would think that I should be able to calculate the center by using an algorithms like:

```
For nodes vertically above the root Node...
  xCoordinate = d.target.x - (d.target.x - d.source.x)/2
  yCoordinate = d.source.y - (d.source.y - d.target.y)/2

For nodes vertically below the root Node...
  xCoordinate = d.target.x - (d.target.x - d.source.x)/2
  yCoordinate = d.target.y - (d.target.y - d.source.y)/2
```

Instead, this doesn't work at all.  I read the API reference and it looks like the "**diagonal()**" method might be able to help but it's not clear how to use it.

In the current code block, I get the predicate text to render by appending a  element to the svg canvas and then appending a  to the  element...

```
var linkTextItems = vis.selectAll("g.linkText")
    .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; })

var linkTextEnter = linkTextItems.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "linkText")
    //.attr("id", function(d) { return d.source.id + ":" + d.target.id; })
    //.attr("predicate", function(d) { return (linksByIdHash[d.source.id + ":" + d.target.id].predicate); })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.target.x) + "," + (d.target.y) + ")"; });

// Add Predicate text to each link path
linkTextEnter.append("svg:foreignObject")
    .attr("width", "150")
    .attr("height", "40")
  .append("xhtml:body")
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .html(function(d){ return "<p>" + (linksByIdHash[d.source.id + ":" + d.target.id].predicate) + "</p>"; });
```

However, the predicate descriptors (i.e. "Predicate 1", "Predicate 2", etc.) are not aligned with the center of each path that they're associated with.

How would I position the predicate text directly on the center of the path?

Answer (score 0):

to find the center of a path you can use the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12063604/2135194) and set the text-align attribute to center

Or:

```
var centroid = path.centroid(d),
    cenX = centroid[0],                //coordinates x of each path
    cenY = centroid[1];                //coordinates y of each path
```

Where `path` is the variable containing you path elements

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Your answer is still vague to me (I'm not that advanced of a coder).  Which selection am I passing into the getCentriod(selection) function and how am I supposed to strap it back into the transform and/or translate functions?

Comment: I'll edit the answer with another option, way easier