# How to get the position X and Y from a polygon element SVG With javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, leaflet

I have a .svg file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="994px"
 height="1415px" viewBox="0 0 994 1415" enable-background="new 0 0 994 1415" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="red_purple">
<g>
    <polygon id="L249" fill="#99637E" points="654.5,400.5 654.5,346.5 691.5,346.5 691.5,368.5 711.5,368.5 711.5,400.5       "/>
    <path fill="#7C6091" d="M691,347v21v1h1h19v31h-56v-53H691 M692,346h-38v55h58v-33h-20V346L692,346z"/>
</g>
</g>
```

I need the position X and Y from the polygon, how do i get?

Comment: Of the polygon centroid? In latitude longitude/svg coordinate space/coordinates relative to page?

Comment: @AndrewReid latitude - longitude and svg coordinate space of the polygon, i need test some options

Comment: How are you using the svg? Is it extracted from a leaflet or d3 map? Or are you overlaying it ontop of a d3 or leaflet map? And if so, how?

Comment: I'll explain, I have a .svg file which I'll load with d3 to a div using
     d3.xml ("mall-map.svg"). mimeType ("image / svg + xml")
which I need to dynamically position titles on the rect or path elements, but there are also polygons, so when I try to access the attributes of an X and Y of the rect, it works without problems

But when the element is polygon, this one does not have those attributes, that's why I'm looking for a way to do that with javascript, to be able to write a title inside the polygon

Comment: Something like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12063604/7106086)? Which would give you the x,y of the center of the bounding rectangle (and then use text-align: middle).

Comment: And for completeness sake, [here's an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pL10kLIv7mSZzuwz7Uce?p=preview) of using the linked code with your svg...